# Error with Google Calendar API - 401 Login required when adding a calendar event

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter, authentication, google-calendar-api

As I am developing an exportation and importing into Google Calendar application with Codeigniter and the Google apiService/apiCalendarService. I have everything set up perfectly, no problem with this, when I authorize my application with Google from this page:

[image]

The contained code is what happens when the redirect happens:

```
session_start();

require(APPPATH . 'libraries/google/apiClient.php');
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/google/contrib/apiCalendarService.php');

$apiClient = new apiClient();
$apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
$calendarService = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

if(isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) 
{
    $apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
} 
else 
{
    $token = $apiClient->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
}
```

After authenticating, I get redirected back to my localhost site with the options in my URL:

```
http://localhost/project/acp/sync/auth/?code=4/DS91JtSJ5_9Q-Z55Kpyh2AicyWdL
```

My script will detect when an authencation has been made by checking the URI segment with `auth` and a `code` query string - so I can start importing events to my Google Calendar account, until that I get this error thrown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={removed API key}: (401) Login Required' in /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/libraries/google/io/apiREST.php:86
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/libraries/google/io/apiREST.php(56): apiREST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#1 /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/libraries/google/service/apiServiceResource.php(187): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest))
#2 /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/libraries/google/contrib/apiCalendarService.php(493): apiServiceResource->__call('insert', Array)
#3 /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/controllers/acp/panel.php(2053): EventsServiceResource->insert('primary', Object(Event))
#4 [internal function]: Panel->sync('auth')
#5 /Users/Me/Sites/project/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /Users/Me in /Users/Me/Sites/project/application/libraries/google/io/apiREST.php on line 86
```

The code that was *importing* an event (code came from Google API samples):

```
session_start();

require(APPPATH . 'libraries/google/apiClient.php');
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/google/contrib/apiCalendarService.php');

$apiClient = new apiClient();
$apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

$event = new Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');
// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1,
                   // ...
                  );
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

I tried Googling the error, but I don't seem to find any solutions with this, do you know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Where do you set your developerKey?

Comment: I set it in the `config.php` where you're normally supposed to.

Comment: Oh, i see you just didn't include `require_once "config.php";`. Then i don't know.

Comment: The config.php gets included in the apiService class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting a `401 Login Required` because the second code is not setting the token:

```
$apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
```

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting a different error: `Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Could not json decode the access token'`

Comment: Use a simple `echo $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'];` to test. Must be  `{"access_token":"...","token_type":"...","expires_in"...}`. Google code is using `json_decode($accessToken, true);` to process it.

Comment: It seems to be `NULL` as of `var_dump` the `oauth_access_token` exists in the array.

Comment: Test this line then: `$token = $apiClient->authenticate();` What value get `$token`?

Comment: That worked, I have an error: `apiException' with message 'Cant add services after having authenticated'`

Comment: Because you are calling some sort of `new apiXXXService($apiClient);` **after** `$apiClient->authenticate();`

Comment: Ah, I see. Now another error: `'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=<api key removed>: (400) Invalid Value'`

Comment: Put a valid email here: `$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');`.

Answer (score -2):

OAuth with Google won't work on a local environment. It needs to be a URL/IP address that Google servers can access for the callback / OAuth handshake.

Grab a domain and test it from there, or set up a forwarder with DynDNS or a similar service.

Comment: I did, I tested it on my development site too, it doesn't work there too.

Comment: If you're using a browser for login, then the keys and tokens will be returned to your app through the session.  You'll need to get API keys from google for "localhost", but it'll work fine.