# Google calendar push notification, login required error

Tags: firebase, google-calendar-api

I am following the docs https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#creating-notification-channels

I am trying to setup my channel to watch for changes to events, using `postman` I am posting to:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxx/events/watch

```
[{"key":"id","value":"xxx@xxx.co.uk"},
{"key":"type","value":"web_hook"},
{"key":"address","value":"https://xxx.firebaseapp.com"},{"key":"key","value":"AIzaSyBkAEZGoQwB0f-Kmq4mCCzm93422up8oQw"}]
```

I keep getting the error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Login Required",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Login Required"
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting this? I can fetch data from the API ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the [401 "login required"](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials), it means that you are using an expired or invalid access.

Check [this Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/google-content-api-for-shopping/F5-CNNMkhDU) on how the process was done on getting the refresh token using the client ID and client secret to implement the authenticated and authorized API calls.

See also references:

- [Google calendar API returns error 401 'login required' on inserting event in public calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167295/google-calendar-api-returns-error-401-login-required-on-inserting-event-in-pub)
- [Error with Google Calendar API - 401 Login required when adding a calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537877/error-with-google-calendar-api-401-login-required-when-adding-a-calendar-event)
- [Using API Key to authenticate a request generates a 401 error](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/jIQaR8ItqGQ)

Comment: I can use get requests fine by appending the key to the url, it doesnt seem to work when doing a post using the same creds.